# 2 bytes addition data stucture in Python

Tags: python-3.x, byte

Does anyone have an idea which data strictures are used in Python to make a program for 2 bytes addition? I've created a model of a 1-bit adder which I have to implement in the program. [1-bit adder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Ws2.png)

Comment: True and False might work

Comment: Every logic gate has true and false functions. I'm talking about the actual data structures in Python I need to use, like (strings,lists,dictionaries,etc..)

Comment: You do not need to use any. You can use the boolean `True`,`False` in python. You could use `0,1 or '0','1'` or create a class of your own liking and use one state as enum `Yeah` and the other as 42 and implement the `__add__` on that ... its not really clear what you need or want or did. maybe a [mre] would help.

Comment: I need them to represent the info to be processed by the program and hold the data.